# Where should I ask questions about CSS architecture?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, site-recommendation

We are building web applications and I'm a front-end developer. In my job, I often have questions about CSS architecture, what is the best way to organize CSS/HTML markup. Examples of these would be questions about SMACSS or other front-end architecture frameworks.

Is this topic appropriate for Stack Overflow?

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking, broad questions of the "what's the best way to do `<foo>`" variety don't really fit anywhere on Stack Exchange. They tend to attract primarily opinion based answers, and often get quickly closed.

Nevertheless, if your questions are specific enough and build around concretes problems you are trying to solve (and not just idle curiosity about "what's the best"), you should try asking them on [Programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/). Programmers is Stack Overflow's subjective little sister, and questions on code structure, architecture and application design are perfectly on topic there.

Before you ask, please take some time to:

- Check out the [site's help center](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help), and especially the [What topics can I ask about here?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) article.
- Browse similar questions. The [css](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=newest&q=%5Bcss%5D%20is:question%20closed:0), [front-end](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bfront-end%5D%20is:question%20closed:0) and [web-development](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bweb-development%5D%20is:question%20closed:0) tags would be a good starting point.

Comment: "Cascading Style Sheets (CSS) is a language for specifying the layout and presentation in general of XML documents (in particular HTML)." I am going to edit the crap out of that tag wiki.

Comment: "What's the best way to do <foo>" is mostly what UX Stack Exchange tackles so I do think there is a place for such questions. Only questions is, if there is any Stack Exchange suitable for such HTML / CSS questions. Still feel the nature of my question is out of place in programmers SE since HTML / CSS are not programming languages.

Comment: @catandmouse Depends on how specific `<foo>` is. "What is the best way to organize CSS / HTML markup" would certainly be off topic everywhere, that's not a question, it's an open ended discussion.